# Telegram sendDocument api, change Title

Tags: php, curl, telegram-bot

I have created a bot, and i want to send file (document) using my bot to my clients, after sending document using following code, title will be full path of my file on my own device ( my pc ), how can I change title to file name only? is that even possible?

Sending code:

```
 protected function perform($method, $params) {
        $url = new Url(TELEGRAM_API_URL . $this->bot->tokken . "/" . $method);
        $fields = [];
        foreach($params as $param => $val)
            if($val != NULL && !cnull::is($val) && substr($param, 0, 1) != '_')
                $fields[$param] = $val;
#
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url->getUrl());
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type:multipart/form-data']);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

            $out = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
#
            $content = json_decode($out);
            return $content;
}
public function sendDocument($chat_id,$_document,$_is_file_id=false,$reply_to_message_id = NULL, $reply_markup = NULL) {
        if($_is_file_id)
            $document = $_document;
        else
            $document = new CURLFile(realpath($_document));
        return self::perform(__FUNCTION__, get_defined_vars());
}
```

---

```
// ......
    $tg->sendDocument(USER_CHAT_ID,"filename.mp4");
```

---

This is result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution by using `->setPostFilename()` for `CURLFile`
 here it is:

change this method:

```
public function sendDocument($chat_id,$_document,$_is_file_id=false,$reply_to_message_id = NULL, $reply_markup = NULL) {
        if($_is_file_id)
            $document = $_document;
        else
            $document = new CURLFile(realpath($_document));
        return self::perform(__FUNCTION__, get_defined_vars());
}
```

to:

```
public function sendDocument($chat_id,$_document,$_title=null,$_is_file_id=false,$reply_to_message_id = NULL, $reply_markup = NULL) {
        if($_is_file_id)
            $document = $_document;
        else{
            $document = new CURLFile(realpath($_document));
            $document->setPostFilename($_title);
        }
        return self::perform(__FUNCTION__, get_defined_vars());
}
```

---

```
// ......
    $tg->sendDocument(USER_CHAT_ID,"filename.mp4","title of file");
```